# Finding a character count in Word VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, ms-word

I'm trying to dynamically generate a word document from an excel spreadsheet. The way that I am going about doing it now is basically manually finding character count, and then will eventually insert a given item at that specific character count. The given item is stored in excel. So it would be like:

Spreadsheet

```
     |    1    | 2        |    3
Char |    50   |  125     |  250
Item | Hello   | Darkness | Friend
```

And then in the word VBA, use

```
Dim myCheck As ContentControl
Dim myRange As Range
Dim rng As Long

rng = ''whatever char is for that column
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(start:=rng, End:=rng)
Set myCheck = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlCheckBox, myRange)
 'what I am doing now is adding a check box dynamically at a given position on the range. This can be either checkboxes that are added or text or whatever.
```

The issue is: how do I find locate a specific point on the a word document? The form that I am trying to insert these into is static, so I can safely assume that if I want to insert it at character 100, each time I make a new form it will insert it in the same place.

I tried using 'word count' character button, but that didn't seem to be accurate. It was consistently 40 or so characters in front of where I wanted it to be. Didn't see a pattern.

Is there an easy way to place my cursor at a location on a document and know how many characters came before it, as counted by the range object? Or is there a more efficient way of locating things on a word document, provided that I cannot alter the word document itself in appearance (can't add grids, grid layouts, tables, or anything like that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the bookmark functionality is what you're looking for.

You can create bookmarks in a static Word Document beforehand and use them as your insertion target... or you can create the bookmarks programmatically with VBA and *then* use the insert text option.

[Examples for using a bookmark to insert text.](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/insert_text_at_or_in_bookmark.html)

```
Sub InsertAtBookmarkI()
  ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmAtBookmark").Range.InsertAfter "Some text here"
End Sub
```

[MSDN Document for creating bookmarks programmatically.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197253.aspx)

```
Sub Mark() 
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:="mark" 
End Sub

Sub ThirdPara() 
 Dim myDoc As Document 
 ' To best illustrate this example, 
 ' Letter.doc must be opened, not active, 
 ' and contain more than 3 paragraphs. 
 Set myDoc = Documents("Letter.doc") 
 myDoc.Bookmarks.Add Name:="third_para", _ 
 Range:=myDoc.Paragraphs(3).Range 
 myDoc.ActiveWindow.View.ShowBookmarks = True 
End Sub
```